# Why is [ssh,scp,rsync,etc] so slow, from a VM to another local machine on my gigabit local network?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, linux-kvm, qemu

I have a VM `A` running the latest archlinux with QEMU, KVM and a Virtio network
card. It is a buildbot and it needs to drop the result on another machine `B` on the
local network.

The VM is started with this command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -net nic,model=virtio -net bridge,br=bridge0 -hda /some/place/disk.qcow2 -m 512 -enable-kvm
```

It is painstakingly slow, 9MB take 1h30 to complete, and it is mangled.

Any other traffic goes at the normal speed of the local network. *Any other* ssh traffic from `A` to another machine that is not `B` is **normal**. Traffic between all machines but `A` is normal.

Help? I don't understand this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The Arch Linux Wiki has [a specific page dedicated to this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU#Virtual_machine_runs_too_slowly). It lists many different possibilities, and I do not know whether one/any/none applies to your VM. They go from the trivial (not enough memory, use KVM, and so on) to the exotic, disabling the cache or the barrier=0 option for mounted filesystems.

You may wish to try those you have not already implemented, and see whether any makes a difference, then report back.

I am a fellow Archer, and the best suggestion I can give you is always to look up the Arch Wiki **first**, because it is really well done.

Comment: Well, I did find the `virtio` solution on this very page. What's more, this problem occurs only with one host. So it seems to be VM independent.